# pandas: subtracting subsequent row of a DF and create a new DF with no column to groupby

Tags: pandas

I am trying to create a new DF by subtracting the subsequent rows of a DF. There is no column that I can use to group by and subtract. the operation should subtract row 0 with row 1, row 2 with row 3, row 4 with row 5, and so on.

df1:

[image]

needs to result in df2:

[image]

I tried to iterate over rows using

`for ii in [0,2,4]:`
and using the value in ii for .iloc, but the result is a column df instead of a row.

Comment: Create an sample input dataframe and show expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the `.diff` of each row from the previous, then select the even elements from that via `iloc`:

```
out = df.diff(-1).iloc[::2].reset_index(drop=True)

print(out)
      a     b      c    d
0  28.0   1.0  147.0 -7.0
1  87.0  10.0  151.0 -7.0
2  -2.0   1.0   77.0 -7.0
```

Not that the subtraction in your sample output isn't correct (unless I mistunderstood something, which is entirely possible). But for your first row columns "a", performing 633 - 605 should be 28, not 27. Then in column "d": 1 - 8 is -7, not -8